Using Components with Buildless
I copied the buildless example from the SolidJS docs then added the simplest possible custom component to it (jsfiddle):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import { onCleanup, createSignal } from "https://esm.sh/solid-js@1.8.1";
      import { render } from "https://esm.sh/solid-js@1.8.1/web";
      import html from "https://esm.sh/solid-js@1.8.1/html";
      
      const Foo = () => html`<em>FOO</em>`;

      const App = () => {
        const [count, setCount] = createSignal(0);
        const timer = setInterval(() => setCount(count() + 1), 1000);
        onCleanup(() => clearInterval(timer));
        return html`<div><div>${count}</div><Foo></Foo></div>`;
      };
      
      render(App, document.body);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

The Foo component content doesn't show. How to use custom components with buildless SolidJS?

Tagged template literals require slightly different syntax than JSX components. Foo in your div component should reference the component definition:
<${Foo}><//>

or
<${Foo} />

If you use a string value instead of the function itself, runtime will create an html element with a tag called 'Foo':
<foo></foo>

The reactive values should be in their function form to preserve reactivity:
${count}

or in case you need to invoke it:
${() => count()}

Solid uses typeof function check on the value to mark it reactive. Invoking the function will extract the value and opt out of reactivity.
Here is how it should look with children:
import { createSignal } from 'solid-js';
import html from 'solid-js/html'
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';

const Foo = (props) => html`<em>FOO ${props.children}</em>`;

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = createSignal(0);
  const timer = setInterval(() => setCount(count() + 1), 1000);

  return html`<div><div>${() => count()}</div><${Foo}>Some Content<//></div>`;
};

render(() => <App />, document.body);

Live Demo: https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/d57a0130-21f1-44cc-af2a-2492682f8c7c
You can pass props as follows:
<${Foo} count=${() => count()}>Some Content<//>

Then you can use:
const Foo = (props) => html`<em>Count: ${() => props.count}</em>`;

Live Demo: https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/42ea98c4-c8a6-415c-ba37-2f119c05fd56
We use function invocation to preserve reactivity. An alternative method would be passing the signal accessor directly:
<${Foo} count=${count}>Some Content<//>

You can read more about it: https://github.com/solidjs/solid/tree/main/packages/solid/html

OK I go that far already. I answered my own Q a few minutes before you posted this. Basically the same with more details.

What is "the component syntax"?

Can you link to docs on this too please? I couldn't find much help re buildless

Yes, great answer except for one thing: How do you pass props like in this extended example -- jsfiddle.net/qenglisq/xo2nsd9w/11?

You can use string interpolation syntax like:
...
html`<div><div>${count}</div>${Foo()}</div>`;

If you want reactivity you have to wrap expressions in a function according to doc:

buildless come with tradeoffs: Expressions need to always be a wrapped in a getter function or they won't be reactive ... because the values are not being accessed inside an effect that the template creates internally, therefore dependencies will not be tracked ...

(demo):
...
return html`<div><div>${count}</div>${() => Foo({x: count()})}</div>`;


You are not using the component syntax but invoking the function directly, which is not correct. Also the use of signal is not accurate, we wrap signals in a function call to preserve reactivity when they are passed between components but your are  using an anonymous function call that invokes the function definition. Solid relies on function calls to preserve reactivity, in complied JSX it is usually done using a getter function which is not available in tagged template literals since there is no compilation. {count} works as long as it is not passed to another component.
